# What are all of these artifacts in my render?

Tags: rendering, particles, shaders, lighting

So I have a scene where that white glowing ball gets engulfs the whole scene and then shrinks.  I am not sure what to change.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating your graphics driver?

Comment: If you mean the "pixelation" looks like a codec issue, render it as image sequence (to see if it is fine), than you can create movie file from this image sequence.